# Pass --config-settings via PIP_CONFIG_FILE

Tags: pip

When building/installing packages with [pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/), I sometimes need to pass *config settings* to the backend à la

```
pip install . --config-settings foo=bar
```

Is is possible to pass those via [pip config files](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/#pip-config-file) as well?